# Trigger with a join included

Tags: mysql, triggers

I would like to do a trigger with a join included.

I need to, dont allow a mechanic to be inserted if he is marked as inactive. I have the table machanic with an attribute called MecActiv that can be active or inactive, also i have a table called reparation that have a foreign key to the table mechanic.
If this attribute on mechanic is inactive, that mechanic cant be on the table reparation so i need a trigger with a join, i cant found how to do it.

Thanks!

P.S: I need the code in Mysql

Comment: Please edit your question and post table structures for both tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you didn't post actual db schema, here it goes.

You don't need a `JOIN` in your case. Your trigger might look like this

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tg_reparation_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON reparation
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.mechanic_id = 
  (
    SELECT IF(IFNULL(mecactiv, 0) = 0, NULL, NEW.mechanic_id)
      FROM mechanic
     WHERE id = NEW.mechanic_id
  );
```

What it basically does it looks if a mechanic with an id that is being inserted is inactive (`mecactiv = 0`) and it is the case it assigns `NULL` to `mechanic_id` violating a `NOT NULL` constraint. Obviously you need to have a `NOT NULL` constrain on reparation table for this to work.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/babd2/1)** demo. *Uncomment last `INSERT` and see if it prevents it.*

Comment: Thanks i'll see in detail later, greetings